# create a trigger a student is not taking repeat course(mysql)

Tags: mysql, triggers

I am using mysql to do a student elective system, register system has a data table, the table field is the sno (student  id) and cno (course id), how do I create a trigger in mysql to prevent students choose to repeat courses?

Comment: Why are you looking for a trigger here? A unique index over both columns should do the work

Comment: Sorry,but it's for my home work

Comment: A Unique key would also be a solution

Comment: Once more: why do you have to use a trigger here? A trigger should be used to execute some action after another - here, you want to receive an error for invalid data, and this is perfectly solved through a unique index

Comment: Thank you! I will try this method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the register table with `student id` and `course id` **together** as primary key. If you can avoid trigger it's easier this way.

If you want to go for the trigger:

```
delimiter //
drop trigger if exists limitCoursesTrigger //
create trigger limitCoursesTrigger before insert on register_table
for each row
begin
    declare msg varchar(128);
    if exists(select * from register_table where studentid=new.studentid and courseid=new.courseid)
    then
        set msg = concat('Error: The student has already registered for this course !');
        signal sqlstate '45000' set message_text = msg;
    end if;
end //
```